# Is a 'res' class folder still necessary in Java when loading images?

Tags: java

I'm working on a game, and I've stumbled across a fews ways to load an image into my program. There are two common ways:

---

- The first (No class folder needed):

  ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("image.png");
  Image i = ii.getImage();

When using this method, you simply *add a folder* to your Project Folder (In Eclipse) and **DO NOT** have to make it an external class folder.

---

- The second option (Class folder needed):

  Image i = ImageIO.*read*(ImageLoader.**class**.getResource("image.png"));

You can only load images this way if you made a resource folder (typically called 'res') and added it as an external class folder to your project.

---

My question is why would you use the second option instead of the first? From my limited experience, it seems like the first option works just the same as the second, just without having to turn the folder you're adding it to into an external class folder.

Answer (score 0):

The first option doesn't work if you package your application as a jar. The second option works in both cases, as an exploded application in an ide or on the hard drive **and** packaged in a jar file.

Comment: Oh. that makes more sense now, don't know why I couldn't catch that when learning. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`new ImageIcon("image.png");` assumes that the image is stored on the file system (in your case, in the current working directory), which raises up some issues - as the working directory isn't always the same location that the jar is stored.

`ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource("image.png"))` embeds the image within the Jar file which resolves the issues associated with the first method as the image is where ever the Jar file is.

It also simplifies installation, as you only need to track the jar files and not all the other "external" files.

`ImageIcon` doesn't report the reasons it fails.  It loads the images in a separate thread, which make diagnosing issues difficult.

`ImageIO` loads the image in the current thread (and returns a fully realised image) but will also generate a `IOException` if the image fails to load for some reason, making a much better way to load images in general.  It also supports (or has the capacity to support) a wider range of images.

In general, using `ImageIO` and embedded images is simpler and easier to work with and is generally the recommended approach for fixed resources